# Java Graphics are not painted with exact coordinates which prevents correct sensing with hitboxes for game

Tags: java, graphics

I am creating a game using Java Swing and Graphics in which I need to sense when the player comes into contact with some obstacles. I am trying to compare when their hitboxes overlap but it seems for some obstacles the exact boxes I see on the screen don't compare exactly to coordinates being compared between player and object. They are close but not exact. Therefore, if the player is slightly to the right or left of the object he will sometimes act as though he touched it even though the hitboxes do not visually overlap.  The printed out coordinates show they overlap even though this is not what is shown on screen.  I can fix this by adding a "wobble" to the inequalities I am comparing, a relatively small, hard coded value which I have to figure out and is not that precise. Is this an issue with Graphics just not being that exact? Is there a way to fix this?

```
 public boolean isTouching(Player p)
          
  {
     
      if (p.getX()<this.getXHitBox()+this.getWHitBox() && p.getX()+p.getWidth()>=this.getXHitBox() && p.getY()+p.getHeight()>this.getYHitBox() && p.getY()<=this.getYHitBox()+this.getHHitBox())
        {   
            //some stuff
            
            return true;
        }
      
      return false;
      
  }
```

XhitBox is the x value of the hitbox (x + xOffset)
YHitBox is the y value (y+yOffset)
HHitBox is the height value
WHitBox is the width value

hitbox is set for obstacles as such:

```
hitbox=new Rectangle2D.Float( (float) (x + xOffset), (float) (y + yOffset), w, h);
```

and drawn like this:

```
 public void drawHitbox(Graphics g)
           
   {   
       
       g.setColor(Color.RED);
     
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2d.draw(hitbox);
        
   }
```

I expected the sensing to only occur when the hitbox visually overlapped but the hitboxes are just slightly off (wobble= approx. 15) from reality. Why is that?
I tried printing out the coordinates and they are different from what is shown on screen! Even if the player is still slightly more to the right than the obstacle, according to the coordinates he is a little more to the left and touching the obstacle.

ie Obstacle will be to the left with x coordinates 88 (for x + width)
Player will be slightly to the right of the obstacle with coordinates 77. What gives?

Comment: To much guess work to provide an answer

Comment: Are you running your code on a Windows system with > 100% monitor scaling?

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc
No, I'm using MacOS and a window with set dimensions using Jframe and JPanel.

Comment: @MadProgrammer
What type of information would be most helpful to provide. Has anyone else noticed this issue?

Comment: Something we can debug; a [mcve]